# Default method implementation to override abstract method

Tags: java, interface, default

The following is not allowed in Java-8:

```
public interface Operator {
    default String call() throws Exception {
      // do some default things
      return performOperation();
    }

    String performOperation();
}

public abstract class AbstractTestClass {
    public abstract String call() throws Exception;
}

public class TestClass extends AbstractTestClass implements Operator {
    @Override
    public String performOperation() {
      // do some operation
    }
}
```

The above fails to compile with the error message saying that the `TestClass` needs to be either abstract or override the call method.

I was thinking that the default method could provide the necessary override. Why does that not work?

I am forced to do something like the following:

```
public interface Operator {
    default String doCall() throws Exception {
      // do some default things
      return performOperation();
    }

    String performOperation();
}

public abstract class AbstractTestClass {
    public abstract String call() throws Exception;
}

public class TestClass extends AbstractTestClass implements Operator {
    String call() throws Exception {
      doCall();
    }

    @Override
    public String performOperation() {
      // do some operation
    }
}
```

This is lacking the clean design that I am looking for.

I see over in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028840/can-a-default-method-implementation-be-used-to-implement-an-abstract-method-in-a) question the solution is to do:

```
public class TestClass extends AbstractTestClass implements Operator {
    String call() throws Exception {
      Operator.super.call();
    }

    @Override
    public String performOperation() {
      // do some operation
    }
}
```

However, the solution does not explain why the compiler does not allow the above clean design. I would like to understand the reasonining and also, see if there is a way I can hide the `call` method in the `TestClass`.

Comment: What is your goal? Why not simply remove the abstract method from the abstract class?

Comment: My guess is that the designers considered it dangerous to automatically implement an unrelated abstract method without forcing the developer to make that choice consciously.

Comment: @assylias because I simply cannot; there are other concrete classes that will not use this interface's default implementation. My goal is to add an interface that will wrap the `call` and delegate to the `performOperation`.

Comment: @JBNizet I think that that is a good guess. It could be argued that the implementation of this interface is making the choice, however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See JLS [§8.4.8.4 Inheriting Methods with Override-Equivalent Signatures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.4):

> This exception to the strict default-abstract and default-default conflict rules is made when an `abstract` method is declared in a superclass: **the assertion of abstract-ness coming from the superclass hierarchy essentially trumps the default method, making the default method act as if it were `abstract`**. However, the `abstract` method from a class does not override the default method(s), because interfaces are still allowed to refine the signature of the `abstract` method coming from the class hierarchy.

You can still use the default implementation from the method, you just have to invoke it explicitly, using `InterfaceName.super.methodName()`:

```
public class TestClass extends AbstractTestClass implements Operator {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return Operator.super.call();
    }
    @Override
    public String performOperation() {
        // do some operation
    }
}
```

Oh, and your `performOperation()` method was missing the `public` keyword and the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: Thank you for the official link. Just a note `@Override` is optional, will add `public`.

Comment: @arin It may be optional, but it helps prevent accidental errors (e.g. typos) and any good IDE will warn you if they are missing.

Comment: yeah definitely, agreed. Although IntelliJ failed to warn me (may be my setting or something like that).

Comment: I don't think Eclipse warns either, at least by default.

Comment: @shmosel True. Guess I'm used to just turn all but 3 warnings on (Non-externalized strings, Method can potentially be static, and Boxing and unboxing conversions).